# Prove that if $z+\frac1z$ is real, then either $|z|=1$ or $z$ is real.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Prove that if $z+\frac1z$ is real, then either $|z|=1$ or $z$ is real.

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw3fu.png)

I am not sure whether my proof is sufficient. So far, I have shown that

$$z+\frac1z = \frac{z^2+1}{z}=\frac{|z|+1}{z}$$

However, I don't think the proof enough, and also I seemed to have proven that they both have to be real and not either... Please advise.

Note: I realised that my proof is wrong, as it was kindly mentioned that $z^2$ doesn't equal $|z|$. I remembered wrongly, it should be $zz*=|z|$ with $z*$ being a conjugate of $z$.

Comment: It is $z^2\neq|z|$

Comment: $|z|$ is the norm of z?

Comment: |z| is the modulus of z in an argand diagram.

Comment: $|z|$ is always real.  You mean $|z| = 1$ or $z$ is real, I think.

Comment: Proof of @RobertIsrael's proposed correction  is straightforward from certain points of view, but you may not yet be familiar with them, or the exercise may want you to take a particular approach. Do you know how the reciprocal of a complex number is related to the number's conjugate and its absolute value (aka modulus)?

Comment: @Blue, no I don't. Would you be able to offer me some advice on it? Many thanks. I just know that $zz*=|z|^2$

Comment: @Blue, I understand now. Reciprocal of a complex number is its conjugate number and has the same modulus but opposite arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By direct evaluation,

$$\Im\left(a+bi+\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}\right)=b-\frac b{a^2+b^2}=0.$$

Then $b=0$ or $a^2+b^2=1$.

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned in the comments, there are some errors in
your calculation ($z^2 \ne |z|$, and $|z|$ is always a real number).

You can get the desired result by exanding $1/z$ with the 
complex conjugate to make the denominator real:

$$
 \text{Im} \left( z + \frac 1z \right) = 
 \text{Im} \left( z + \frac {\overline z}{z \overline z} \right) = 
 \text{Im} \, z - \frac{\text{Im} \, z}{|z|^2}  =
 \text{Im} \, z  \cdot \left( 1 - \frac{1}{|z|^2} \right)
$$
is zero if and only if $$\text{Im} \, z = 0 \text{ or } |z| = 1 \, .$$

Therefore
$$
z + \frac 1z \in \Bbb R \Longleftrightarrow z \in \Bbb R \text{ or } |z| = 1 \, .
$$

Comment: May I ask why you focused on the imaginary part?

Comment: @CCC: A complex number $z = x+iy$ is *real* if its imaginary part $y$ is zero.

Answer (score 5):

If $z+\dfrac1z$ is real $\iff z+\dfrac1z=\overline{z+\dfrac1z}=\bar z+\dfrac1{\bar z}$

$$\iff (z-\bar z)\left(z\bar z-1\right)=0$$

Now  if $z-\bar z=0,z$ is real

Else use $z\bar z=|z|^2$

Comment: I understand your comment about $z-\bar z=0$, but your next statement about $z\bar z=|z|^2$, I am quite confused. Shouldn't it be $z\bar z-1=0$ and therefore, $z\bar z=1$?

Comment: @CCC,  And $z\bar z=|z|^2$

Answer (score 2):

Another way:
\begin{align}
z+\frac{1}{z}&=\rho(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)+\frac{1}{\rho}(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)\\
&\left(\rho+\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\cos\theta+i\left(\rho-\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\sin\theta
\end{align}
And
$$
\left(\rho-\frac{1}{\rho}\right)\sin\theta=0\implies \rho=1 \text{ or } \theta=0 \text{ or } \theta=\pi
$$